# FilePond: if allowBrowse is true then a file open dialog is always displayed when the onactivatefile event is fired

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am using the onactivatefile event to open a file when the user clicks it.  But how can I prevent the file open dialog from being displayed also, without setting allowBrowse to false.

Comment: It shouldn't open the browse dialog? Can you create a test case on https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hopper-3xgm0 showing the problem.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in the sandbox.  But I am using NextJS and ReactJS function components, it is not exactly like the sandbox.

Comment: I added an <input type='text' readOnly /> with display: none above my FilePond compent and it seems to solve the problem.